# Javascript onmouseover trying to add " to text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I am very new to javascript and web development in general. I am trying to make it so that when you hover over text a small text box pops up with a paragraph in it. The problem is that I need to add " in the text however when I do that the script doesn't work as it recognizes " as part of the code.

I am using nhpup popups to do that [nhpopup site](https://www.nicolashoening.de/?twocents&nr=8)

This is what I am trying to add " to

```js
/*

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Code for link-hover text boxes
By Nicolas Höning
Usage: <a onmouseover="nhpup.popup('popup text' [, {'class': 'myclass', 'width': 300}])">a link</a>
The configuration dict with CSS class and width is optional - default is class .pup and width of 200px.
You can style the popup box via CSS, targeting its ID #pup. 
You can escape " in the popup text with &quot;.
Tutorial and support at http://nicolashoening.de?twocents&nr=8
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

The MIT License (MIT)

Copyright (c) 2014 Nicolas Höning

Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
THE SOFTWARE.
*/

nhpup = {

    pup: null,      // This is the popup box, represented by a div    
    identifier: "pup",  // Name of ID and class of the popup box
    minMargin: 15,  // Set how much minimal space there should be (in pixels)
                    // between the popup and everything else (borders, mouse)
    default_width: 500, // Will be set to width from css in document.ready
    move: false,   // Move it around with the mouse? we are only ready for that when the mouse event is set up.
                   // Besides, having this turned off initially is resource-friendly.

    /*
     Write message, show popup w/ custom width if necessary,
      make sure it disappears on mouseout
    */
    popup: function(p_msg, p_config)
    {
        // do track mouse moves and update position 
        this.move = true;
        // restore defaults
        this.pup.removeClass()
                .addClass(this.identifier)
                .width(this.default_width);

        // custom configuration
        if (typeof p_config != 'undefined') {
            if ('class' in p_config) {
                this.pup.addClass(p_config['class']);
            }
            if ('width' in p_config) {
                this.pup.width(p_config['width']);
            }
        }

        // Write content and display
        this.pup.html(p_msg).show();

        // Make sure popup goes away on mouse out and we stop the constant 
        //  positioning on mouse moves.
        // The event obj needs to be gotten from the virtual 
        //  caller, since we use onmouseover='nhpup.popup(p_msg)' 
        var t = this.getTarget(arguments.callee.caller.arguments[0]);
        $jq(t).unbind('mouseout').bind('mouseout', 
            function(e){
                nhpup.pup.hide();
                nhpup.move = false;
            }
        );
    },

    // set the target element position
    setElementPos: function(x, y)
    {
        // Call nudge to avoid edge overflow. Important tweak: x+10, because if
        //  the popup is where the mouse is, the hoverOver/hoverOut events flicker
        var x_y = this.nudge(x + 10, y);
        // remember: the popup is still hidden
        this.pup.css('top', x_y[1] + 'px')
                .css('left', x_y[0] + 'px');
    },

    /* Avoid edge overflow */
    nudge: function(x,y)
    {
        var win = $jq(window);

        // When the mouse is too far on the right, put window to the left
        var xtreme = $jq(document).scrollLeft() + win.width() - this.pup.width() - this.minMargin;
        if(x > xtreme) {
            x -= this.pup.width() + 2 * this.minMargin;
        }
        x = this.max(x, 0);

        // When the mouse is too far down, move window up
        if((y + this.pup.height()) > (win.height() +  $jq(document).scrollTop())) {
            y -= this.pup.height() + this.minMargin;
        }

        return [ x, y ];
    },

    /* custom max */
    max: function(a,b)
    {
        if (a>b) return a;
        else return b;
    },

    /*
     Get the target (element) of an event.
     Inspired by quirksmode
    */
    getTarget: function(e)
    {
        var targ;
        if (!e) var e = window.event;
        if (e.target) targ = e.target;
        else if (e.srcElement) targ = e.srcElement;
        if (targ.nodeType == 3) // defeat Safari bug
            targ = targ.parentNode;
        return targ;
    },

    onTouchDevice: function() 
    {
        var deviceAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
        return deviceAgent.match(/(iphone|ipod|ipad|android|blackberry|iemobile|opera m(ob|in)i|vodafone)/) !== null;
    },
    
    initialized: false,
    initialize : function(){
        if (this.initialized) return;

        window.$jq = jQuery; // this is safe in WP installations with noConflict mode (which is default)

        /* Prepare popup and define the mouseover callback */
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            // create default popup on the page
            $jq('body').append('<div id="' + nhpup.identifier + '" class="' + nhpup.identifier + '" style="position:absolute; display:none; z-index:200;"></div>');
            nhpup.pup = $jq('#' + nhpup.identifier);

            // set dynamic coords when the mouse moves
            $jq(document).mousemove(function (e) {
                if (!nhpup.onTouchDevice()) { // turn off constant repositioning for touch devices (no use for this anyway)
                    if (nhpup.move) {
                        nhpup.setElementPos(e.pageX, e.pageY);
                    }
                }
            });
        });

        this.initialized = true;
    }
};

if ('jQuery' in window) nhpup.initialize();
```

```html
<a onmouseover="nhpup.popup('Action Relating to or affecting the fundamental nature of something; far-reaching or thorough. This is what we offer at Rad Surfing Bali. We provide the most radical way of learning how to surf.');" href='#'>Radical.</a>
```

Please help me add a " to the text in the html script.

Regards,
Kraz

Answer (score 0):

You should escape `''` chars with `\`.
Like this

```
<a onmouseover="nhpup.popup('Action Relating to or affecting the fundamental nature of something; far-reaching or thorough. This is what we offer at \'Rad Surfing Bali\'. We provide the most radical way of learning how to surf.');" href='#'>Radical.</a>
```

Here is working example https://jsfiddle.net/xkj66svc/

Comment: Hello. and thanks for replying. Would it be possible to add " instead of ' as when I try to do it, it messes up the javascript.

Comment: Quick workaround would be to replace double quotes with single and vice versa. Check here https://jsfiddle.net/xkj66svc/1/